# FAQ - screenshots from bicycles.SE

Tags: bug

Here i a screenshot from the ServerFault FAQ. The images are from bicycles.stackexchange.com!
Could this be fixed please?

**Edit**. I had not noticed that it was the case for all FAQs on stackexchange. Still: shouldn't they be screenshots of the actual web sites for those that do not have the sketchy beta layout?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

The image is the same on all sites FAQ window, it is just a generic image to show the inbox, it just happens to be from Bicycles.

Comment: isn't that counter-intuitive?

Comment: At least they aren't from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would imagine the default FAQ's are produced automatically on creating a site, it would be a bit of a pain to add a unique image for each site. Particularly for sites that change design when they get out of beta.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Maintaining individual faq images for each site would be a bit of a nightmare.  Sketchy is pretty simple and since all sites start with it, possibly easily recognizable.  We used the bicycles site as any content that makes it into the images is going to be safe and understandable to most people.

Comment: "understandable to most people" is the key. It seems to be working too, otherwise this would have been raised previously.