# The case of the vanishing question

Tags: discussion

This morning there was [this question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/2157/9278) on the front page of meta. Now, just a couple of hours later, it's not there. Why did it disappear from the front page? Is it because of the number of downvotes? I can't recall ever noticing this kind of thing before.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean from before you dropped your answer on it. I just looked and it shows you last modified it and its on the front page.

Comment: I don't see it either. Maybe it's a new feature that removes really low voted questions from the front page, as I see some -5's still there

Comment: It's most definitely gone from the 'active' list, but still shows up in 'Questions'. Weird. Apparently if you pile enough hate on a question it stops being active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 2008 when we started the network, any question at -4 or below is suppressed from the front page.

This has always been so.

Comment: Hrm. Well my screenshots show it hanging on the front page at -7 though... It doesn't disappear until -8. Unless its a caching thing.

Comment: it is -8 for metas and -4 for main sites.

Comment: Ok but the upvotes and comments on this question suggest that I'm not the only one who never noticed it before. :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's what I'm seeing. When you click on the main page, it's gone. But I always sort by Questions>Active and it shows up there.  I'm on Chrome, for what it's worth.

**Update:**  We've tested with [this question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2149/faq-screenshots-from-bicycles-se) (apologies to whoever that was), and it appears that 8 downvotes is the threshold for removing it from the main page, but not the "Active Questions" page.  I have screenshots of the whole thing.

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjzNs.png)
[Questions/Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zq69.png)
[Questions/Newest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI0I9.png) (This line of ss is from first question to disappear)

[Bicycles 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgj9X.png)

[Bicycles 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7W9m.png)

[Bicycles 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbgby.png)

[Bicycles 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDrir.png)

[Bicycles 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5fAY.png)

[Bicycles 4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyo2N.png)

Comment: While I get the same results when going through the same process it still doesn't explain why the post disappeared from the front page, although I suspect there is a downvote threshhold at play.

Comment: @John Possibly more than 5 downvotes? We *could* quickly empirically test this if we don't get a response...

Comment: 5 might be the magic number. I certainly can't recall seeing a post with more than that many downvotes on the front page. Of course if you want to start a test then go for it.

Comment: Turns out 8 is the magic number

Comment: Thanks, now I won't have to think about this all weekend. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Anything for science!

Comment: Spot the guy who's living up to the stereotype of the anal sys admin!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, sir.